# ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin component is not working in ATG

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

I searched for the indexing component (**ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin**) in the dyn/admin (dynamo administrator). 
I'm not able to locate it.
Even, I tried to access it directly by typing it's URL path. I'm getting an error saying
"Nucleus Service /atg/endeca/index/commerce/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin not found" [(error snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNOOP.png)

The DB is in remote place and so is the Endeca. What could be the problem? I tried searching for this issue. I didn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Platform Details : 
**ATG** version  : **11.1**,
**Java** version : **1.7.0_79**, 
Server       : **Weblogic (12c)**

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using is incorrect.  The relative path should be `/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin`.

or

`http://<yourhost>:<port>/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin`

The `dyn/admin` component browser has a search feature which allows you to locate components when you are not sure of the path.  You can access this as follows:

1. From the `dyn\admin` homepage select component browser
2. Click the link near the top of the page in the component browser `Search`
3. Type in the name or part of the name of the component you are looking for

Comment: Hi, I've also tried the URL you suggested. That's also not working. The problem is the search leads to the exception. when,  search all option(2nd radio button) is used.

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score -1):

In my machine, the browser URL is like the one below:

`http://commerceserver.example.com:8080/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin/`

Comment: Blatant copy of my answer!

Comment: @bated - I just gave my answer (and I included complete nucleus path), I guess stackoverflow is for that purpose!